# Einen Rat geben vs einen Rat erteilen

Tags: meaning-in-context, usage

Both of this means equally to give advice. Is there any subtle usage differences between the two?

From using reverso, it seems that they are very similar. But maybe I am missing something hence I ask.

Comment: "Erteilen" sounds more formally. I don't see a difference in meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Etwas erteilen* has a slight subtile overtone of **hierarchy** - It is normally done by someone with more competence or authorithy (like a teacher or parent), while *geben* doesn't have this.

Other than that overtone, the meaning is the same.

Comment: Additionally, "erteilen" is less frequent in the spoken language, it is more formal. But that ties in exactly with fofro's answer.

Comment: Einen Rat gibt oder erteilt man doch immer auf Basis der Vermutung in dieser Angelegenheit mehr Kompetenz zu haben. Ich sehe da keinen Unterschied zw. "Rat geben" und "erteilen".

Comment: @userunknown Du kannst deinem Freund den Rat *geben*, dass er seine Frau verlassen soll. *Erteilen* kannst du ihm diesen Rat eher nicht. Ich denke, das macht den Unterschied am besten klar.

Comment: Indem Du das auf mich und meine Freunde und deren Frauen beziehst machst Du es überspezifisch. Offenbar hoffst Du so die Hierarchie aus der Beziehung zu entfernen. Aber die Situation, in der jmd. einem anderen einen Rat gibt, basiert immer auf einer Asymmetrie an Wissen. Wüsste der andere, was man ihm raten will, bräuchte es den Rat nicht. Zumindest muss der Ratgebende davon ausgehen, dass er einen Rat zu geben hat, den der Empfänger nicht hat - von merkwürdigen Umständen abgesehen, in denen es opportun scheinen mag, zu etwas zu raten ohne Hoffnung, der Rat sei nützlich.

Comment: @userunknown Einen Rat kann man auch aufgrund einer puren *Meinung* oder *eigener Erfahrung* (die natürlich von der *eigenen Wahrnehmung* geprägt ist) geben - Da braucht's kein *Wissen* dazu. Ich glaube, du hast dich hier ein bißchen zu sehr festgebissen.

Comment: Ob sich der Rat nun auf Wissen stützt, auf Erfahrung, auf Halbwissen oder Gerüchte und Vermutungen ändert aber nichts daran, ob ich einen Rat gebe oder erteile. Deswegen habe ich mir nicht die Mühe gemacht das weiter aufzudröseln, aber wenn Du drauf bestehst … . Man kann auch einen Rat geben um einer dritten, beobachtenden Partei den Eindruck zu geben, man sei in der Lage Rat zu geben usw., aber für die Frage ob man gibt oder erteilt spielt es keine Rolle.

Comment: Frage: Kann ein Berater einem Staatspräsidenten einen Rat erteilen? In Hierarchien erteilt man ja eher Anweisungen.